# Display input text box view Asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

asp:textbox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Visible="true" Text****="<%# Eval("quatity","{0:######}")"**** />

how will i do this in mvc3 view.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for flexible text editor with e.g. multiline properties:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.propertyName)
```

You can simply add a input box with `Html.TextBoxFor` and `HtmlTextboxFor` always creates a `textbox (<input type="text" ...)`. While the `EditorFor` looks at the type and `meta information`, and can render another control or a template you supply.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.propertyName)
```

PropertyName specifies the property value to be displayed in the textbox.

Comment: You can also use TextBoxFor. Assuming you're using Razor: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.propertyName) or when using WebForms <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.propertyName). In this "m" stands form Model, it's a shortcut code.